# How can I suppress output in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My assignment has 3 values in the defined function and those 3 values are Reactors. One condition in the assignment states that " Do not display information about mixing time if a given reactor is not used in production (e.g. if x3=0 the message about the third reactor will not be displayed)."

```
def Report2(x1,x2,x3):
    if x1==0:
       return None
    if x2==0:
       return None
    if x3==0:
       return None
    y=mixing(x1)+mixing(x2)+mixing(x3)
        return y
```

this is my code as of the moment, the problem is that whenever i assign the values (0,0,0) and print I get the word None. What I want is for nothing to be displayed instead.

Thank you

Comment: `k=Report2(x1,x2,x3)` then `if(k): print(k)`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? _My assignment has 3 values in the defined function and those 3 values are Reactors._ Are we expected to know exactly what a "Reactor" is here? _the problem is that whenever i assign the values (0,0,0) and print I get the word None._ What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result and print in a conditional.

```
result = Report2(0,0,0)
if result:
    # will not execute if result == None
    print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use condition after the function executed:

```
def Report2(x1,x2,x3):
    if x1==0 or x2==0 or x3==0:
        return None
    y=mixing(x1)+mixing(x2)+mixing(x3)
    return y

result = Report2(0,0,0)
if result:
    print(result)
```